# adminJS buildAuthenticatedRouter login fails

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, adminjs

**What I'm trying to do**

I am trying to connect adminJS to a MongoDB database and implement an authenticated adminJS portal. I am using the [authenticated](https://docs.adminjs.co/installation/plugins/express) example here to start, which is based off postgres, and then I have modified it based off code from [this tutorial](https://dev.to/bcncodeschool/creating-an-admin-area-in-five-minutes-with-adminbro-express-mongodb-mongoose-1j11) in order to use mongoDB instead.

**The problem**

The problem is, when I run `node server.js` I am able to see the login portal at localhost:3000/admin and I can correctly put in username and password, and I see the message "Login worked!" but then it just reloads the login page.  I think something is going wrong with the authentication routing, because when I remove authentication and just use buildRouter instead, it works fine.

**My code from index.js**

```
import AdminJS from 'adminjs'
import * as AdminJSExpress from '@adminjs/express'
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import * as AdminJSMongoose from "@adminjs/mongoose"
import session from 'express-session'
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo'

import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

import Users   from './app/models/user.js';
const PORT = 3000

const DEFAULT_ADMIN = {
  email: 'admin@example.com',
  password: 'password',
}

AdminJS.registerAdapter({
  Resource: AdminJSMongoose.Resource,
  Database: AdminJSMongoose.Database,
})


const authenticate = async (email, password) => {
  if (email === DEFAULT_ADMIN.email && password === DEFAULT_ADMIN.password) {
    console.log("Login worked!");
    return Promise.resolve(DEFAULT_ADMIN)
  }
  return null
}

const start = async () => {
  const app = express()

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI,{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
  // useFindAndModify: false,
  // useCreateIndex: true
});

const sessionStore =  MongoStore.create({
    client: mongoose.connection.getClient(),
    collectionName: "session",
    stringify: false,
    autoRemove: "interval",
    autoRemoveInterval: 1
    });
const adminOptions = {
  resources:[Users],
  rootPath:"/admin"
}

const admin = new AdminJS(adminOptions);

// const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress.default.buildRouter(admin);;
  const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress.default.buildAuthenticatedRouter(
    admin,
    {
      authenticate,
      cookieName: 'adminjs',
      cookiePassword: 'sessionsecret',
    },
    null,
    {
      store: sessionStore,
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      secret: 'sessionsecret',
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      },
      name: 'adminjs',
    }
  )
  app.use(admin.options.rootPath, adminRouter)

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`AdminJS started on http://localhost:${PORT}${admin.options.rootPath}`)
  })
}

start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here had to do with using the wrong value for DB_URL. Once I fixed that, this code pretty much worked.

Comment: To expand on that: I had the same problem.  I created a `.env` file and added `DB_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1/testDB`